# Swapping characters

Tags: python

How do I swap characters; in a word, for example?

For example, what method do I use to swap letters `'a'` and `'b'` around in a `'aabbab'` to make it `'bbaaba'`?

I've tried using the `.replace()` method, but it only changes letters `'a'` to `'b'`:

```
row = raw_input('Make a row: ')
print row.replace('a', 'b')
```

Comment: `"".join(["a" if c == "b" else "b" for c in "aabbab"])`? `"aabbab".translate(string.maketrans("ab", "ba"))`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: do you really think OP is going to be helped by code-golfed comments with no explanation?

Comment: @Wooble possibly not, which is why I only commented. I wouldn't consider either of those golfing, though.

Comment: Aapoman, you should post what you've tried so far.

Comment: this question is treated overly harshly, i think

Comment: @Aapoman: I think you meant to write "characters" instead of "variables" in your first sentence, could that be? Swapping variables is something quite different from what you are describing.

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions or do:

```
newthing=[]
for letter in 'aabbab':
    if letter=='a':
        newthing.append('b')
    elif letter=='b':
        newthing.append('a')
''.join(newthing)
print(newthing)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can swap in Python 2.7 using this code:

```
row = raw_input('Make a row: ')
newrow = ""
for letter in row:
  if letter == "a":
    newrow += "b"
  elif: letter == "b":
    newrow += "a"
  else:
    newrow += letter
print newrow
```